# clean a string extracting all the non numeric characters

Tags: objective-c

I'm quite new in Objective C. I'm trying to convert the following string `5896.3454A` into a numeric string `58963454`. Any idea how to do it.

I have been trying with `NSScanner` class, but I'm not sure, whether this is the best approach.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: sorry Cyrille, you are right I should have a post the piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to use a string replacement with regular expressions:

```
NSString *mixed = @"5896.3454A";
NSString *pattern = @"\\D"; // Pattern for "not a digit"
NSString *digitsOnly = [mixed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:pattern
                                withString:@""
                                   options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [mixed length])];
```

Comment: Many thanks Martin, this is a good approach which will help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C contains a lot of little tricks. Here is a silly one to solve your problem.

```
NSString *string = @"5896.3454A";

NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSCharacterSet *nonDigits = [digits invertedSet];
NSArray *digitSubstrings = [componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigits];

NSString *result = [digitSubstrings componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

`result` will have only the digits in `string`.

I create a character set with all the digits. I use `invertedSet` to get a set with every character other than the digits. This is straight forward, next is the silly part. Next I split the string into an array of substring. This will have the effect of stripping out all the non digit characters, but all the digits are broken up into substrings. In this case, `digitSubstrings` will be `@[@"5896", @"3454", @""]`. Not a problem, I join all the substrings back together to create the final string.

Comment: Hi Jeffery, I really like your approach. That would solve by far my problems. Thanyou very much

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also by
yourString mentioned in your question
NSInteger newInt = [ [ [ yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"A" withString:@""] integerValue];

ADDED: NSInteger newInt = [ [ @"123.123A" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] integerValue]; combining NSString and NSScanner methods, integerValue ignores everything beginning with the first appearance of a character

You find it in the NSString class. Whether this is the better solution depends on the unwanted literals in your "string-number" you want to replace/delete.

Comment: Thanks macrene for the additional comments